# keyboard doesn't work with blender (OSX)

Tags: interface, osx

I've got this issue. My keyboard works fine in OS and other applications but when I start Blender have to hold down opt or my keyboard writes signs like: "ß∂ƒ¸˛√ªﬁø" instead of "asdfgh".

Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score -1):

It's because OSX keyboards have their own Apple Mac layout, incompatible with Windows PCs Maybe the link below helps

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202676

Comment: But I only use Mac. When I start blender the problem start and when I restart the computer it works fine.

Comment: I must ask: did you download Blender for MacOS? It's available at https://www.blender.org See also https://www.lynda.com/Blender-tutorials/Using-Blender-Mac/87088/95346-4.html If nothing helps, you may report a bug.

Comment: I don't think a build of Blender for another platform would even run on macOS.